# Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {...}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead

Tags: reactjs

**Code that gives error:**

```
  const request = axios.get(baseUrl)
```

**Response from axios.get(baseUrl):**

```
[
   {
      title: "sarko blog",
      url: "facebooook.com",
      likes: 3,
      author: {
         username: "davitg",
         name: "dato",
         id: "61ca1a774685c0b29fa4d14d"
      },
      __v: 0,
      id: "61ca2148881f6885742c72fc"
   }
]
```

It gives error because author is object. (Objects are not valid as React child)

how can I fix it

toString() is not solution because request doesn't return promise and I have problems with then() function

Comment: You get this error when you attempt to return an object / array from a React component, instead of a ReactNode / JSX.

Comment: @Summer how can I return array from JSX or ReactNode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably trying to display an object inside your JSX. You can't do something like:

```
<div> author: { response[0].author } </div>
```

Instead, you can do:

```
<div> author username: { response[0].author.username } </div>
<div> author name: { response[0].author.name} </div>
<div> author id: { response[0].author.id } </div>
```